# jspdf - exporting a div is getting cut off when being saved to a PDF. pictures attached :)

Tags: angular, export, jspdf

i'm making use of the jsPDF library and i'm running into some issues. For some reason, when im exporting a div (the invoice) with a width of 800px or 100%, it's getting cut off. and looks a bit like picture 2... I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here?

This is what my save function looks like

```
  savePdf() {
    let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

    const pdfTable = this.content.nativeElement;

    doc.html(pdfTable, {
      callback(rst) {
        rst.save('one.pdf');
      },
      x: 10,
      y: 10
    });

  }
```

## Picture 1:

#### [image: html]

## Picture 2:

[image]

Looked up the docs and can't find anything related to this problem

Comment: appreciate the reply @KJ, where did you get the 210mm - 20 points wide measurement from? is there any way i can increase it?

Comment: i've managed to get it working for the first page but when it gets to the second page, it sticks blank pages and its rotating x degrees lol... i've managed to stick it in a stackblitz if you want to take a crack at it :smile:

i'm using jsPDF & html2canvas

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-save-to-pdf-export